# Strange image height behaviour in iOS (and possibly other mobile) devices?

Tags: html, ios, css, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I have the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <ul id="images">
      <li class="image">
        <img src="portrait.jpg"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="trailing-content">
      <p>line 1</p>
      <p>line 2</p>
      <p>line 3</p>
      <p>line 4</p>
      <p>line 5</p>
      <p>line 6</p>
      <p>line 7</p>
      <p>line 8</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

With the following CSS:

```
body, html{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}

body, div, ul, li{

  border:0;
  margin:0;
  padding:0

}

ul, li{

  list-style:none;

}

#page{

  width:75%;
  height:100%;

  margin:0 auto;

}

#images{

  position:relative;

  width:100%;
  height:70%;

  overflow:hidden;

}

#images .image{

  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  text-align: center;

}

#images .image img{

  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;

  margin:0 auto;

}
```

The intended result here is that the visible image is a maximum of 70% of the screen height at an given time. This works perfectly in desktop versions of the main browsers (tested Firefox, Chrome, Safari), as you can see with this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gzuaf).

But when in a mobile browser (specifically in Safari and Chrome Mobile on my iPhone 4 running iOS6), the image remains large (cut by the `overflow:hidden` rule in the CSS) and does not constrain it's size appropriately.

iPhone screenshot:

[image]

And here is the desktop version acting as it should:

[image: desktop]

Strangely, this only happens if their is subsequent content following the `#images` tag (in this case `#trailing-content`). This indicates that the image is ignoring its parent dimensions and only honouring the actual iPhone screen size.

**Update**

I still have no idea what's causing this, and have noticed that iOS7 actually works as it should. But I'm not willing to dump iOS6 support here, so have decided to put this question to bounty.

Comment: try adding media query @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

Comment: @San Where? Don't see how media query is relevant...

Comment: you mean your image is not scaling down..I'm unable to understand your problem.

Comment: @San The image does not scale to it's parent height (70% of screen) in mobile browsers, but does in desktop browsers.

Comment: do you have an absolute url where i can check this on my iphone

Comment: @San Yes you can see it [here](http://www.sonsandsons.co.uk/dev/sarah2/test.html) (check desktop vs mobile for difference).

Comment: I ran your code in safari using the iphone agent and it works fine

Comment: @San See added screenshots in updated question.

Comment: well its fine as per your css or=f 70 and 30%

Comment: @San Please tell me where in my CSS it says 30%, and how the two images posted above seem identical in behaviour?

Comment: see the posted image here. You ul height is 70% so what remains is 30% of the viewport. and you have changed the font size when resize to mobile view for which i said use media query. See the image here http://s16.postimg.org/bjtpvwkwl/image.jpg

Comment: @San this isn't about font-sizing or box-sizing. Have you read the question? I'm aware that the parent div is indeed 70% of the screen. What I'm saying is that the image is not resizing to the correct height of its parent. Note, in my mobile screenshot, that the image has been cut where the bounding parent box stops, as opposed to the image being correctly resized to fit into its parent, as per the desktop screenshot...

Comment: oh damn...im sorry that was stupid of me.. let me try

Comment: :-) I'm guessing the lack of other responses here means I've stumbled on a possible discrepancy between the box-models in mobile vs desktop browsers.

Comment: im trying to work this on flex box..lets see gimme few minutes

Comment: @San I'm not holding my breath. Been trying to work this out for a few hours now. This may need a guru.

Comment: im sorry...i guess we have come to a snag...sorry

Comment: I'm stuck at a prinzhorn skrollr for last 2 days :). Cheers

Comment: did you try this with jquery?

Comment: @San there is some jQuery for progressive enhancement, but I'm interested in a pure HTML/CSS solution for this particular problem. I'm less bothered about a fix, and more interested in understanding why Safari/Chrome mobile are acting differently.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile devices use webkit. Have you tried any of the webkit css options?

e.g.

```
body {
   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Here are some options for webkit with good documentation (I think there are more):

http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit

EDIT:

on another note what happens when you remove the max-height property?

Comment: Yes, have tried the one in question, and a few others. It's probably worth mentioning that I'm not unversed in web-development so I won't be mindlessly applying CSS and then reporting back. I've given a perfectly simple piece of boilerplate code as a testbed for anybody who wants to try it. I'm grateful for any effort, but if the effort is minimal then it can be more of a hindrance. If you're serious about the question, you'll know if you've solved the problem or not.

Comment: @shennan If you are 'not unversed in web-development' then you should already know that there are no out-of-the-box solutions to such issues. The bounty is not a wage, and SO is not a workplace. If you want to sit and wait for ready solution, then hire someone instead of grumbling and downvoting all around.

Comment: @Adam Haven't downvoted and haven't grumbled. And actually, in my experience, with a bug like this there usually is an out-of-the-box solution. Any solution is an out-of-the-box solution in my eyes. But so far there have been no solutions in the answers. I stated I was grateful, but if somebody would like to answer successfully they should at least reproduce the bug themselves to test. Not a huge ask. From where I'm standing, you're the one grumbling. :-)

Answer (score -1):

I would try the following:

```
max-width: 70%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

That way, the image should resize properly without cropping. However, I've had cropping issues with large images where I simply had to copy and resize it for it to work properly.

Answer (score -2):

Avoid percentages relative to screen size when dealing with height. Setting percentage-based constraints on both height and width with nesting elements and hidden overflow is like asking for troubles. Do you see the image is cropped so that its full height exactly fits the screen?

Of course, you can continue with trials and errors, but in my opinion it's a waste of time (and nerves too).

Instead, just set `max-width: 100%` and for example `max-height: 500px` to avoid oversizing on large screens, and let your content scroll down freely.

If you want your page to be fully responsive, use **[CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)**.

Comment: I think this is a bit of a cop-out. All desktop browsers I have tested make this stack of HTML/CSS work exactly as expected, so to advise avoiding "percentages relative to screen size when dealing with height" is a little drastic based on the quirks of a mobile browser. Also, avoiding the use of percentage heights dumps on a pretty large proportion of full-screen page layouts. Many modern websites make use of 100% height layouts.

Comment: It's just my advice. If you want to avoid scrolling, then you must scale _everything_ equally. BTW, try to comment out all `width` settings from the CSS (or replace them with `max-width`) and see what will happen. Maybe this will put you on the right track.